# Using $request_uri in a redirect as query string parameter

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to encode the value of `$request_uri` within a query string as in the following redirect?

```
error_page 401 = @error401
location @error401 {
    return 302 /sign-in?t=$request_uri;
}
```

The example above works but `$request_uri` is appended as is, so that a 401 redirect on `/foo?a=1&b=2` becomes literally `/sign-in?t=/foo?a=1&b=2` instead of something like `/sign-in?t=/foo%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2`

Comment: All I've managed to find was a [10 years old enhancement request](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/52) and a person, who managed to [abuse the nginx JS support in order to implement this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73050303/1026). Still can't believe that I can't find something this basic...